# React .props is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have initial state for a component 'Posts'

inside reducer like this:

```
import {FETCH_POSTS, NEW_POST, ASSISTANT_MANAGER, BARTENDER, OPEN_MODAL} from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {},
    showComponent: false,
    selectedJob: {}

}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import postReducer from './postReducer'
export default combineReducers({
    posts: postReducer,
})
```

/components/Posts

```
class Posts extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedJob: ""
    };

  }

  _onButtonClick(selected_post, e) {

    this.setState({
      selectedJob:selected_post,
      showComponent:true

    });
    console.log('my current props', this.props)



  }
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.fetchPosts();
  }




  render() {
    const keys = generateKey(new Date().getTime())
    var dictionary = this.props.posts
    const postItemsArr = Object.keys(dictionary).map(post=>dictionary[post])
    const number = 0
    const postItems = postItemsArr.map(
    post=>(

           <Jumbotron  key={generateKey(post.positiontitle) + generateKey(post.businessId)} >
             <div className="position">{post.positiontitle}</div>
             <br></br>
             <BusinessName businessnameType={post.businessname} />

             <br></br>

             <JobDescription jobDescription={post.description_sanitized} />
             <br></br>


             <Button onClick={this._onButtonClick.bind(this, post)}>DETAILS</Button>

           </Jumbotron> 


      ))
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Jobs Listings </h1>

        {postItems }
        {this.props.showComponent ? <ModalComponent selectedJob={this.state.selectedJob}/>: null}

      </div>
    );
  }
}


Posts.propTypes = {
  fetchPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  newPost:PropTypes.objects,


}

const mapStateToProps = state => (

{

  posts: state.posts.items,
  newPost: state.posts.item,
  showComponent: state.posts.showComponent

});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(Posts);
```

What I'm trying to do is _onButtonClick(selected_post, e){
  I want to set the props here which sets showComponent to True.
}

When I use this.props.showComponent(true) it says .showComponent is not defined.

inside my actions file I have showComponent Action which should dispatch the props but doesn't as expected.

```
./actions/postActions
import {FETCH_POSTS, NEW_POST, OPEN_MODAL} from './types';

export const showComponent = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type:OPEN_MODAL,
        payload:false
    })
}
export const fetchPosts = () => dispatch => {
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/?filters')
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(posts => dispatch({
    type:FETCH_POSTS,
    payload:posts.results,
}))
```

}

Overally, how would I dispatch an action  to reducers without having to use export connect like how I did for fetchPosts

Comment: You need an action to toggle `showComponent`, not using `this.setState`.

Comment: For your second question, you need to use [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

Comment: I'm trying to store showcomponent value on my props and not state so it can be easily accessible throughout my components

Comment: Yes I see that, but why are you doing `this.setState({ showComponent: true })` and then `console.log(this.props.showComponent)`? That's not how you update a reducer. You need an **action** that updates the reducer state for `showComponent`.

Comment: Can you also write a simple pseudo code so I can get a better understand and usage of mapdispatchtoprops. How would I use this in my case?

Comment: Right so when I do this.props.showComponent where showComponent was my action as defined above export const showComponent that's where I dispatch it to reducer with type and action.

Comment: When I use this.props.showComponent() it says it's not defined. Why?

Comment: It's because you aren't using the `mapDispatchToProps` function. You should talk to whoever wrote the code for `{fetchPosts}` to understand how it works. I've never seen a setup like this, so it is unique to your app which is why you are having trouble finding any examples.

Comment: Here is full usage docs for `mapDispatchToProps`: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options